# How can i publish taken data from subscribing broker in mqtt mosquitto?

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

I have MQTT Broker (Mosquitto) in different two devices. 
They are working. I set bridge between them. 
I can publish data from one to another with pub_mosquitto. 
I want to get data from any topic in internet broker(broker.hivemq.com) like http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/
I can take data from any topic in that website brokers but i can not publish taken data to another my broker at the same time. 
I want to use my broker pub/sub. 
My broker will take data from any broker and publish  it to my bridged broker. How can i do this ?

I drew and wrote below:

[image]

Comment: Update the question with your bridge configs and a diagram of the arrangement of the brokers.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT bridges can be configured to work in multiple ways

- To take local messages and forward them to a remote broker
- To take remote messages and forward them to the local broker
- To do both of the previous statements

e.g. for mosquitto

```
topic # out // local to remote

topic # in // remote to local

topic # both // bridge in both directions
```

Full details on how to configure mosquitto bridges can be found in the man page [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm633)

The only limit on what topics can be bridged is based on the normal ACL for the user the local broker uses to authenticate with the remote broker.

To achieve what you want you need to create 2 bridges, one between Broker 1 & Broker 2 that should have the direction of `both`. This can be setup in the config for either Broker 1 or Broker 2 (but not on both).

Secondly on Broker 1 you can create a bridge to the HiveMQ broker. This should probably have a topic mapping line like:

```
topic temperature in
```

This will take any messages published to the HiveMQ broker and bridge them onto Broker 1 which will then bridge them to Broker 2